# OpenCV - Mat.data corrupted after VideoCapture

Tags: opencv, webcam, mat

I'm trying to read video from a webcam, and process it on CUDA. Frame must be converted into 1D array before that, but when I use Mat::data image appears to be corrupted (all I see is some grey mess). imShow with the same Mat works fine.

```
    captureA >> A;

    cvtColor(A, A, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    init_texture(A.data);
    lawTex(450, 375, texture);

    imshow("A", texture);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does your `init_texture()` require that the input data must be memory continuous?

Comment: Yes - input is then copied into gpu memory by cudaMemcpyToArray

Answer (score 0):

As `cudaMemcpyToArray()` within `init_texture()` requires the input data memory to be continuous, you should make sure about this before calling.

For your case, it can be like this:

```
if (A.isContinuous()){
    init_texture(A.data);
}
else{ // not continuous, transfer first
    std::vector<uchar> data;
    data.assign(A.datastart, A.dataend);

    init_texture(&data[0]);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that mat A is continuous. It looks just like A.data points to somewhere else. 
All other operations, like resizing, cvtColor, or even copying to GpuMat works fine.